# How to create user in Oracle ASM only for selecting specific table without giving SYS privileges

Tags: oracle

Is there any way to create common user for Oracle ASM for accessing(selecting) fixed table such as X$KFFXP? I looked up few documents and reaches the user should be given SYSDBA or SYSASM. I just wonder if such user can be created without SYS privileges given like a common Oracle Instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t.
In oracle versions where both sysdba and sysasm roles exist, the users with only sysdba role are read only users.
There is a good chance that sysdba eventually will be removed. Let’s hope oracle does not forget something like read only access for asm monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

ASM instance does not any datafiles. Does not have DBA_USERS table(view) the  only place where you can store user's password is the password file. Created using `orapwd` command, visible via `V$PWFILE_USERS` view.

Only "exceptional" users can have their password stored in this file.